# Adding/modifying SuggestOracle after construction of SuggestBox in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

All of the information that I can find for SuggestBox and MultiWordSuggestOracle suggests that the only way to set an oracle for a suggest box is when it is constructed. I don't think this makes sense, though, since there is a default constructor that does not accept an oracle and creates one for you, presumably empty. That doesn't do much good. What I'm looking for would be methods like `setSuggestOracle(MultiWordSuggestOracle)` or `addToSuggestOracle(String)`, but I can't find anything in the documentation suggesting how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can change the instance of the `SuggestOracle` after the `SuggestBox` has been created, but you can access it with `SuggetBox::getSuggestOracle()`.  From there you would have to cast to the implementing class to make changes to it; the `SuggestOracle` base class itself doesn't provide anything.  So something like:

```
SuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
SuggestBox box = new SuggestBox(oracle);

try {
  MultiWordSuggestOracle multiWordOracle = (MultiWordSuggestOracle)box.getOracle();
  multiWordOracle.add("This awesome suggestion.");
} catch (ClassCastException e ) {
  // the oracle was not what you thought it was
}
```

Comment: Why not just work on the oracle variable instead of getting it from the suggest ?

Comment: @Guillaume Yes, you can do that.  But, I was trying to show how you would get the Oracle from the suggest box.